# Simple indexed select query takes 350 seconds (?!) even though Filtered 100.00 "Using index condition"

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-5.7, performance, slow-log

My logs show that the query being explained here took **352.19 seconds** (and similar times for other similar queries where the `contact_id` and `execute_at` were different).

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `automations`
WHERE
    (`contact_id` = 22638
        AND `job_class_name` = 'App\Jobs\MyJob'
        AND `execute_at` = '2018-12-15 16:43:00')
        AND `automations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Result of EXPLAIN:

```
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys                  | key                            | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
|----|-------------|-------------|------------|------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|---------|-------------------------|------|----------|-----------------------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | automations | NULL       | ref  | cId_job_executeAt_delAt_unique | cId_job_executeAt_delAt_unique | 780     | const,const,const,const | 1    | 100.00   | Using index condition |
```

I am inexperienced at optimizing MySql, but my guess would be that the Explain looks great, right?

Why on earth would queries like this be taking 350+ seconds? How can I diagnose and fix?

P.S. This is related to the `E_WARNING: Error while sending STMT_PREPARE packet. PID=*` [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53469793/470749) I frequently see.

```
CREATE TABLE `automations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `job_class_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `execute_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cId_job_executeAt_delAt_unique` (`contact_id`,`job_class_name`,`execute_at`,`deleted_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `automations_contact_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1519 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Another error I'm seeing (quite possibly related) is that ~20 times per day, I see `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ` on various tables. It always looks as if a user is trying to register on my site multiple times in the same second. I wonder if the unique indexes I have on certain timestamp columns could be causing some of the slowness. (I only have those unique indexes as a remnant of an ETL that needed it because a 3rd party accidentally duplicated some records.) I don't have many simultaneous visitors, but I wonder if it's related.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My queries that I thought took 352 seconds really only took 0.352 seconds! ‍♂️

https://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-what-time-format-does-dbgetquerylog-return showed me that Laravel's `DB::getQueryLog()` shows "time" as milliseconds (microseconds multiplied by 1000), not seconds.

What an embarrassing mistake (poor assumption). So I need to edit my 500-point bounty question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469793/e-warning-error-while-sending-stmt-prepare-packet-pid/54374937?noredirect=1#comment95579631_53469793

Answer (score 0):

The optimal index for *this* query would be a composite index with 4 columns, in any order:

```
INDEX(contact_id, job_class_name, execute_at, deleted_at)
```

And, depending on the order you pick, you can get rid of one of the existing KEYs.

Watch out for backslashes.  `'App\Jobs\MyJob'` *may* be treated as `App[LF]obs[CR]yJob` or `AppJobsMyJob`.

<strike>352 seconds is really unreasonable.  Perhaps something else was going on, and blocking access to the rows and/or the table?</strike> (The 352s was bogus.)

"Using index condition" is not the same as "Using index".  The latter indicates a "covering index", which is not practical for this query and table.

Comment: I updated my question to show that I'm already using a 4-column composite index, so that isn't the root cause of the slowness. I don't *think* the backslashes are problematic; the query often works fine. Is there anything else you could elaborate on for your last 2 paragraphs or any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: (I think Laravel is appropriately handling the backslashes via parameterized query.)

Comment: @Ryan - Turn on the slowlog in hopes of catching something useful.  If you can spot the query taking a long time, do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` (as root) to see if you can spot some other take doing something.  (I'm running out of ideas.)

Comment: Interesting. E.g. getting alerts from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33253451/470749. Thanks.